# Why Dapper does not UPDATE data to MS Access even though no exception?

Tags: sql, ms-access, dapper

I used the following code to update, but it is not working. The call is successful; there is no exception. But update does not reflect in database.

When I change `@id` to 2, it succeeds.

```
OpenSqlConnection();

tm = new testmyy();
tm.ID = 2;
tm.namemy = "1233";

// update fails
string query2 = "UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = @namemy WHERE ID = @ID";  

// update successful
// query2 = "UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = @namemy WHERE ID = 2";   

int i = conn.Execute(query2, tm);
```

Comment: as per [my reply on github](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/916): "Can I ask: what is the underlying database here? That may be relevant". Also: if you can define "is not working", that would be great; does it throw an exception? or just do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DynamicParameters`. Modify your code something like below:

```
var param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add("@ID", 2);
param.Add("@namemy", 1233);
string query2 = "UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = @namemy WHERE ID = @ID";
int i = conn.Execute(query2, param, .....);
```

Comment: I don't see any way in which I would expect this to behave differently to the code in the question, frankly

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is "access" (from the github chain). The access ADO.NET provider is kinda broken - it allows named parameters, but access itself doesn't - it just supports `?` placeholders. More: the order it adds the placeholders is not based on the order the named parameters were found. So basically: access is **very** strict about parameter order, which **isn't meant to matter** when using named parameters. I think what is happening in your case is that the access provider is changing:

```
UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = @namemy WHERE ID = @ID
```

to

```
UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

but adding `@ID` then `@namemy`. This essentially **reverses** the parameter order.

---

Now, how to fix this. Dapper supports pseudo-positional parameters, *intended* for providers that don't even *pretend* to support named parameters. Access pretends to, but is not very good at it. So: to trigger dapper's pseudo-positional parameter handling, use:

```
UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = ?namemy? WHERE ID = ?ID?
```

Dapper will treat this as:

```
UPDATE testmyy SET namemy = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

and will know to use strict parameter ordering. Basically, it'll work.

Comment: Does `DynamicParameters` addresses this issue in some way? We are using Dapper with MS Access for one of our projects. We had the problem you mentioned with earlier version of that project which was using ADO.NET. We resolved it by ordering the parameters properly. Further, when we started using Dapper for that project, we never encountered the issue. OP is saying the same thing here that when he replaced his POCOs with `DynamicParameters`, issue resolved.

Comment: @Amit fun fact: reflection has no concept of *member order*, so the order of the parameters added via type is currently non-deterministic. The order of the parameters from `DynamicParameters` is *probably* insertion order, but I'd actually need to check whether it is implemented as a list vs a dictionary to be sure. Another fix I've been considering for a while is to change the regular code to order by "first index of the parameter string in the source SQL", which is quite tempting and would solve the "access" problem. The `?foo?` approach solves the same issue via different means.